# Save-file dialog is throwing an exception

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I have a bit of a problem with my text editor program with the open dialog,it works perfectly when you actually select a file but if you cancel out it throws an exception as shown:

```
 openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

 if (saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory.Equals(saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory))
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Didnt make a selection");
 }
 else
 {
     txtUI.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
 }
 saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Please click on the file you want to open";
```

I have tried this if-else statement but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where is the exception log?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the *return value* of `ShowDialog()`:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

If the user cancelled the dialog, the result would be `DialogResult.Cancel`.

Comment: thanx alot for the help

Answer (score 0):

> Put your code in try catch block like this

```
try{
      if (saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory.Equals(saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory))
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Didnt make a selection");
    }
    else
    {
        txtUI.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Please click on the file you want to open";
   }catch{}
```